# Awk editing with field delimiter

Tags: awk

Imagine if you have a string like this 
`Amazon.com Inc.:181,37:184,22`

and you do `awk -F':' '{print $1 ":" $2 ":" $3}'` then it will output the same thing.

But can you declare `$2` in this example so it only outputs `181` and not `,37`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know you could print each argument without a delimiter but then it won't have the same output on this string: Cisco Systems Inc.:20,45:20,49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the field separator so that it contains either `:` or `,`, using a bracket expression:

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{ print $2 }' file
```

If you are worried that `,` may appear in the first field (which will break this approach), you could use `split`:

```
awk -F: '{ split($2, a, /,/); print a[1] }' file
```

This splits the second field on the comma and then prints the first part. Any other fields containing a comma are unaffected.